# Which fields does -[NSResponder presentError:] show?

Tags: macos, cocoa, error-handling, nserror, nsalert

Is there any documentation about how the [`-[NSResponder presentError:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/presentError:) method works? I'm trying to create `NSError` instances in my library whose `userInfo` values show as much useful information to the user as possible. I'm having a tough time.

I started out using just `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey`. Seeing that it assigned the `messageText` property of the generated `NSAlert` (bold font, topmost label), I next tried adding on `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`, which I thought would then fill in the `informativeText` property, for a non-bold explanation under it. I also added `NSURLErrorKey`, since this library deals with files and it would be helpful.

The resulting `NSAlert` doesn't show the original `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey` value at all, with the new `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` now becoming the `messageText`. It also doesn't expose the `NSURLErrorKey` at all, either.

Is my only option to write my own error presentation method and special-case this library's domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the `NSError` keys interact with `presentError:` is documented in the Error Handling Programming Guide under [Localized Error Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH202-SW4).

It includes a diagram detailing what goes where. As the docs note:

> Failure reason
>
> A brief sentence that explains the reason why the error occurred. It is typically part of the error description. Methods such as presentError: do not automatically display the failure reason because it is already included in the error description. The failure reason is for clients that only want to display the reason for the failure.

If you want to rearrange the fields in an `NSError` object prior to presentation, this is best done by overriding `willPresentError:` to return an adjusted error object.

Regarding fields like `NSURLErrorKey`, it is expected that you will have included this in `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` or `NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey` if you want to display it. While it is called the "recovery suggestion," the documentation is explicit that it may be used "as a purely informative message supplementing the error description and failure reason."